# Is there a characterization of linear isomorphisms of the space of skew symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

Let $M_n^s$ denote the $\scriptstyle\binom{n}{2}$ dimensional space of $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrices. Is there a characterization of linear isomorphisms that take $M_n^s$ into itself. If $n=2$ then any isomorphism 
$$Q:M_n^s\rightarrow M_n^s$$ is of the format $$Q(X)=k X.$$

Comment: For every isomorphism $M_n^s\to M_n^s$ there is a corresponding invertible matrix. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: The space of $2 \times 2$ skew-symmetric matrices is one-dimensional, so the only linear operator is scalar multiplication. For larger matrices there's no such characterization.